# Make program parallel using OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I'm new at OpenMP. I know, that if I use `#pragma omp parallel for` I  can make one for loop working parallel. But what should I do with this kind of for loops?

```
    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j=1; j<=N; j++)
    for(k=1; k<=N; k++)
    {
        A[i][j][k] = A[i][j+1][k]+A[i][j-1][k];
    }
```

Comment: A possibility: move the j loop outside and parallelize the in

Comment: Parallel over i

Comment: @tim18, thank you for responding. Am I right that it will look something like for(j) then #pragma omp parallel for and after that the other loops?

Comment: Yes or it may be ok to parallelize over i in your original order (avoid collapse)